# JavaFx 2 application freezing when running task

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx-2, race-condition

I'm new in JavaFX 2 and I'm having some troubles using multithreads in JavaFX. The problem I'm facing is that the application simply freezes and I can't find why. I believe there is a race condition in some place, but I can't locate it.
As JavaFx's documentation says, I've created a class extending "Service" and I'm running it with "start()":

```
public class ProcessadorTarefas extends Service<StatusRetorno>{

    private final ITarefa tarefaPadrao=new TarefaVerificarImpressora();
    private final ITarefa tarefa;
    protected Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    public ProcessadorTarefas(ITarefa tarefa) {
        this.tarefa = tarefa;
    }

    public void processar() {
        if(getState()==State.READY)
            start();
        else
            restart();
    }

    @Override
    protected Task<StatusRetorno> createTask() {
        return new Task<StatusRetorno>() {
            @Override
            protected StatusRetorno call() throws Exception {

                    /*THE CODE FREEZES HERE*/

                StatusRetorno status = tarefaPadrao.processar();
                if (status == StatusRetorno.SUCESSO)
                    status = tarefa.processar();
                return status;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

The class that calls "processar" method listen onSuceed, onCancelled and onFailed of ProcessadorTarefas class:

```
public abstract class ControladorBase implements IProcessamentoDispatcher, EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent> {

    @Autowired
    protected ControladorDialogoMensagem dialogoMensagem;
    protected ITarefa tarefa;
    protected String mensagem;
    protected Set<IProcessamentoListener> listeners = new ConcurrentSkipListSet<IProcessamentoListener>();

    protected void executarTarefa(ITarefa tarefa) {
        executarTarefa(tarefa, null);
    }

    protected void executarTarefa(ITarefa tarefa, String mensagem) {
        this.tarefa=tarefa;
        this.mensagem=mensagem;
        despacharProcessamento(StatusProcessamento.INICIADO, null);
        final ProcessadorTarefas processador=new ProcessadorTarefas(tarefa);
        processador.setOnSucceeded(this);
        processador.setOnCancelled(this);
        processador.setOnFailed(this);
        processador.processar();
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(WorkerStateEvent evento) {
        StatusRetorno status= (StatusRetorno) evento.getSource().getValue();
        despacharProcessamento(StatusProcessamento.FINALIZADO,status);
        if(status==StatusRetorno.SUCESSO)
            exibirMensagemSucesso();
        else
            exibirMensagemErro(status);
    }

    /*UNIMPORTANT CODE*/

    private void despacharProcessamento(StatusProcessamento statusProcessamento, StatusRetorno statusRetorno) {
        for (IProcessamentoListener listener : listeners)
            listener.processamento(new EventoProcessamento(this, statusProcessamento,statusRetorno));
    }

    /*ADD AND REMOVE LISTENERS CODE*/
}
```

As the code freezes on "call" method, the listener isn't called and the main dialog isn't shown, cause this code is called after user logged in.

**INFORMATION ADDED**

This code is executed after the login dialog is closed and before the main dialog opens, so, there isn't any javafx element in the screen:

```
public class App extends Application implements IDadosSubmetidosListener, IProcessamentoListener {

    /*variable declaration ommited*/   

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext contexto = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/spring/appContext.xml");
        App aplicacao = contexto.getBean(App.class);
        SecurityContextHolder.setStrategyName(SecurityContextHolder.MODE_GLOBAL);
        aplicacao.iniciar();
    }

    private void iniciar() {
        cancelarOperacoesTEF();
        controladorDialogoLogin.adicionarListener(this);

        /*opens login dialog*/

        controladorDialogoLogin.abrir();
    }

    private void verificarDadosEAbrirTelaPrincipal() {

        /*after the user logged in, close login dialog*/

        controladorDialogoLogin.limparListeners();
        controladorDialogoLogin.fechar();
        if (verificadorFuncaoUsuario.usuarioAutorizado()) {
            if (verificadorFuncaoUsuario.usuarioCaixa())
                verificarSeECFValidoECadastrar();
            else
                controladorDialogoPrincipal.abrir();
        } else {
            controladorDialogoMensagem.adicionarListener(this);
            controladorDialogoMensagem.exibirAlerta("Você não tem credenciais que te permitam acessar este sistema!");
        }
    }

    private void verificarSeECFValidoECadastrar() {
        verificadorNumeroSerieECF.adicionarListener(this);

        /*this code call that class shown above*/

        verificadorNumeroSerieECF.verificarNumeroSerieECF();
    }

    private void terminarCadastroECFEAbrirTelaPrincipal() {
        controladorDialogoCadastroECF.limparListeners();
        controladorDialogoCadastroECF.fechar();
        controladorDialogoPrincipal.abrir();
    }
}
```

As you can see, the code is called in the main Thread, is this the correct place to call that code, or I should call it from a dialog?

Comment: What does `tarefaPadrao.processar()` and `tarefa.processar()` do? Can you supply the code for these functions? Or an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) (preferable to posting a lot of code) which demonstrates the issue?  Are you trying to update (off the JavaFX application thread) any UI elements or properties UI elements are bound to (which is illegal)?  Your question mentions a dialog but there is no code display a stage in your posted code.

Comment: Take a thread dump or simply pause threads in eclipse.

Comment: @jewelsea 'tarefaPadrao.processar()' and 'tarefa.processar()' calls some dll codes. I noticed that you asked about the dialog, I've updated the question to clarify the enviroment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't know that the Service class only works when it is called from a JavaFX component. So, to solve it I adapted this part of code to run in a single thread. In others parts of the program, the service is started from JavaFX's component (a button for example) and it works well.